# Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.168.65.7:53:

Tags: spring, docker

Error -> **Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:47354->192.168.65.
7:53: read: connection refused**

I code fullstack application and this application is running correctly in local . I want to use docker for this fullstack application . Application's backend is written in Spring boot . Also i used Mysql database.
when i docker compose up i get this error -> **Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 192.168.65.4:47354->192.168.65.
7:53: read: connection refused**

application.properties :

```
server.port=8080
#CodeFirst, DbFirst
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# DataBase Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Dockerfile :

```
**FROM openjdk:20 ADD target/hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar EXPOSE 8080 ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]**
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: hospitalproject
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
    networks:
      - springmysql-net
    depends_on:
      - localhost

  localhost:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - springmysql-net
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=springstsudent
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hospital
      - MYSQL_USER=springstudent
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=springstudent

networks:
  springmysql-net:
```

If you need any extra information to solve this problem i can edit this question . Could you please help me